# Filling up diagonal elements in a 2D array in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

Is there any pythonic way of filling up the diagonal values in a 2D array?
Or do we have to go with the conventional way:

```
for i in range(size):
   for j in range(size):
      if i==j:
         data[i][j] = -1
```

Comment: Pretty easy to do as a list comprehension: `[[-1 if i == j else 0 for j in range(size)] for i in range(size)]`

Comment: @Daniel don't think that will work the way you want it to

Comment: using numpy: numpy.diag([-1]*size)

Comment: As several people state here, numpy has pretty convenient functions for that. However, with regards to your looping algorithm, you should note that if you have a conditional within a nested loop which assures equality of the loop counters for the only code inside - you simply don't need the nested loop. Just use a single loop and its counter for each index...

Comment: There is no need to create an inner loop, if all you do there is `if i == j`. So if you just have that outer loop it will probably be fine, unless your array is really large. Otherwise use numpy.

Answer (score 1):

You could use numpy.fill_diagonal().

```
a = np.zeros((3, 3), int)
np.fill_diagonal(a, 5)
a
```

OUTPUT

```
array([[5, 0, 0],
       [0, 5, 0],
       [0, 0, 5]])
```

Refer to https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.fill_diagonal.html.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

ndarray = np.zeros((10,10))
np.fill_diagonal(ndarray, 1)

print(ndarray)
[[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]]
```